# Apply Pareto probabilities to n items in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list in sorted order:

```
countries = ['USA', 'GB', 'RU', 'CN']
```

How would I assign `np.pareto` probabilities to each item in `countries`? The total probability should be no greater than 1.0

Desired outcome:

```
countries = [{
              {"name": "USA",
               "power": 0.24},
              {...}
             }]
```

I would later access the data like so:

```
np.random.choice(countries[name], p=countries[power])
```

Comment: What is it you want to ask exactly - is it how to assign probabilities to the items, or how to set the axis limits?

Comment: how to assign probabilities to the items.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest changing the last part of your question so it's clear that's what you want to know. In fact, if that's what you're asking, there's probably no need to talk about plotting at all, so if you can frame your question (and your sample code) in a way that doesn't involve matplotlib or graphics, that would probably make it clearer.

Comment: riight. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a shape parameter for `np.random.pareto`, and I'd assume you just want a list of dictionaries, and not a list containing one set containing dictionaries. This might be what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np

countries = ['USA', 'GB', 'RU', 'CN']
pareto_shape = 1.

prob = np.random.pareto(pareto_shape, len(countries))
prob /= np.sum(prob)

out_list = []
for p, country in zip(prob, countries):
    out_list.append({
        'name': country,
        'power': p,
    })
print(out_list)
```

At least, that would give you something that looks like

```
[
    {"name": "USA",
     "power": 0.24},
    {...}
]
```

But if you want to access data using `np.random.choice`, what you really want to use is

```
import numpy as np

countries = ['USA', 'GB', 'RU', 'CN']
pareto_shape = 1.

prob = np.random.pareto(pareto_shape, len(countries))
prob /= np.sum(prob)

print(np.random.choice(countries, p=prob))
```